# When is the first recorded use of a fireship?

Tags: war, naval

When were the first accounts of fire ships? They were used in The American Revolutionary War but is there any other sources saying that these were used beforehand?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fire_ship answers this fairly well thanks to Thucydides, History of the Peloponnesian War.